# TicTacToe (again!), but with difficulty levels, undo, and hints

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I'm learning Python after a 30+ year break from programming, got bored with the usual TicTacToe exercise, so went a bit wild adding functionality to it to make something that's a bit more fun to play than losing to the computer every time.

Now reached the stage of aimlessly noodling around with it, which suggests to me that fresh, and experienced, eyes would be handy. I would very much welcome a review of any/all aspects of the code. Be brutal - I can take it!

A few points:

1. It is written as a module, as I'm rubbish at UIs and I want to use this to practise with. Would it help if I also posted something that *used* the module? I have a fairly scraggy tkinter thing that I am using as a testbed if that would help.
2. It works. Rather nicely I think - in fact I am quite proud of it. This of course is a Big Red Flag that a code review is needed ;)
3. Nevertheless, it is possible that I have grossly abused something-or-other, but I've tried hard to get PEP8/PEP257 stuff right, and to comment lightly and selectively. So it shouldn't be too hard to work out what I am driving at. I hope.
4. It's a bit big - runs to 8 pages printed, sorry about that.

```
"""Module to support playable versions of TicTacToe (Noughts and Crosses)

by phisheep 2017

VARIABLES (all should be treated as read-only)
    - USER, COMPUTER, EMPTY - Player objects
    - cells[] - list of Cell objects representing the playing board
    - lines[] - list of Line objects ditto
    - moves[] - list of Cell objects representing moves made in current game
    - game_over - boolean
    - winning_line - Line object, or None
    - winning_player - Player object, or None

CLASSES
    - Player() - One for each player, and EMPTY
        player.symbol - arbitrary symbols for each player, default 'X', 'O' and ' '
        player.opponent - the other (non-EMPTY) player
    - Cell() - One for each cell on the board
        cell.lines[] - list of Lines this cell is in
        cell.set(player) - sets a cell and checks for win/loss/draw        
    - Line() - One for each row, column and diagonal on the board
        line.cells[] - list of Cells in this line
        line._value - SUM of the player values in this line

PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
     - reset_board() - clears the board for a new game
     - available_cells() - returns list of available Cells
     - board_list_symbols() - returns list of values on the board
     - board_XY_symbols() - return 3x3 list of symbols on the board
     - undo() - undoes moves to the previous USER move
     - hints(player) - returns list of Cells that a good opponent
                       might want to move in
     - play(difficulty,player) - returns the Cell computer has moved in
                                (after making the move!)

INTERNAL FUNCTIONS
    These fall into three groups:
    - _play_...            one for each difficulty setting (returning a completed Cell, or None),
                           which call...
    - _make_...            to make a particular sort of move (returning a completed Cell, or None),
                           which may call ...
    - _list_possible_...   to list candidate moves (returning a list of Cells) 

ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS

     Harvey, B (1997), Computer Science Logo Style: Volume 1 Symbolic Computing (2nd Edn),
     MIT, Cambridge Mass
     ISBN 0–262–58151–5 (set of 3 volumes)
     ISBN 0–262–58148–5 (volume 1 only)
     Chapter 6 at this link
        https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/pdf/v1ch06.pdf

     ... for detailed discussion of tactics    

"""
import random

_CENTRE = _EDGES = _CORNERS = tuple()

cells = []
lines = []
moves = []

game_over = False
winning_line = None
winning_player = None


class Player:
    """ One instance for each of the two players USER and COMPUTER, also NULL """

    def __init__(self, value, symbol):
        self._value = value
        self.symbol = symbol

    @property
    def opponent(self):
        if self == USER:
            return COMPUTER
        return USER


# These assignments are here (rather than in __init__()) as they are used as default
# arguments in function definitions further down
USER = Player(10, "X")
COMPUTER = Player(1, "O")
EMPTY = Player(0, " ")


class Cell:
    """ One instance for each cell in the TicTacToe board.

    ATTRIBUTES
        - player - a Player object: USER, COMPUTER or EMPTY   
        - index - cell's position in cells[] list
        - xpos, ypos - cell's position in x,y co-ordinates
        - lines[] - Line objects, populated by Line() instance
    FUNCTIONS
        - set(value) - sets a cell value and end-game variables     
    """

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.index = i
        self.player = EMPTY
        self.xpos = self.index % 3
        self.ypos = self.index // 3
        self.lines = []

    def set(self, player=USER):
        """ Return a filled-in cell, having checked for end of game """
        global game_over, winning_line, winning_player
        if game_over:
            raise RuntimeError("Attempt to make a move when the game is over")
        if player not in [USER, COMPUTER]:
            raise ValueError("Cell must be set to either USER or COMPUTER")

        self.player = player
        moves.append(player)  # recorded in case of undo

        for line in self.lines:
            if line._value == 3 * self.player._value:
                game_over = True
                winning_line = line
                winning_player = self.player
                return self
        if not available_cells():
            game_over = True
        return self

    def _reset(self):
        self.player = EMPTY
        pass


class Line:
    """ One instance for each row, column and diagonal 

    ATTRIBUTES
        - cells[] - list of Cells in this line
        - value - (read-only) SUM of player values in cells in this line
                    (used for testing line contents)

    """

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.cells = [cells[i] for i in args]
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.lines.append(self)

    @property
    def _value(self):
        """  Return total value of cells in this line. """
        return sum([cell.player._value for cell in self.cells])


def __init__():
    """ Initialise classes and module variables """
    # Warning: contains 'magic numbers' specific to this TicTacToe
    # implementation. All gathered here so they don't clutter up
    # the rest of the code.
    #
    # (... Except the Player objects, which had to be moved out
    # because of getting default arguments right)
    global _CENTRE, _EDGES, _CORNERS

    for i in range(9):  # cells
        cells.append(Cell(i))

    for i in range(0, 9, 3):  # rows
        lines.append(Line(i, i + 1, i + 2))
    for i in range(3):  # columns
        lines.append(Line(i, i + 3, i + 6))
    lines.append(Line(0, 4, 8))  # diagonals
    lines.append(Line(2, 4, 6))

    _CENTRE = (cells[4],)
    _EDGES = (cells[1], cells[3], cells[5], cells[7])
    _CORNERS = (cells[0], cells[2], cells[6], cells[8])


# PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

def reset_board():
    """ Reset board to starting position. """
    global game_over, winning_line, winning_player
    for cell in cells:
        cell._reset()
    moves.clear()
    game_over = False
    winning_line = None
    winning_player = None


def available_cells():
    """ Return list of empty cells. """
    return [cell for cell in cells if cell.player == EMPTY]


def board_list_symbols():
    """ Return list of all cell symbols. """
    return [cell.player.symbol for cell in cells]


def board_XY_symbols():
    """ Return 3x3 list of all cell symbols. """
    output = [] * 3
    for cell in cells:
        output[cell.ypos].append(cell.player.symbol)
    return (output)


def undo():
    """ Undo moves back to last *user* move. """
    global game_over, winning_line, winning_player
    if game_over:  # because it's not over any more!
        game_over = False
        winning_line = None
        winning_player = None

    if len(moves) != 0:
        last_move = moves[-1]
        if last_move.player == COMPUTER:
            last_move._reset()
            moves.pop()

    if len(moves) != 0:
        last_user_move = moves[-1]
        last_user_move._reset()
        moves.pop()


def hints(player=USER):
    """ Return list of possible winning moves by opponent. """
    return (_list_possible_wins_blocks(player.opponent) or
            _list_possible_wins_blocks(player) or
            _list_possible_forks(player.opponent) or
            _list_possible_forcing_moves(player.opponent))


def play(difficulty, player=COMPUTER):
    """ Execute a playing strategy, returning the cell moved in. """
    # (This is a little scrappy and could do with tidying up)
    #
    move = [_play_loser, _play_random, _play_easy, _play_hard,
            _play_handicap_2, _play_handicap_1, _play_expert]
    if difficulty not in range(len(move)):
        raise ValueError("No such difficulty setting - " + str(difficulty))
    return move[difficulty](player)


# PLAYING STRATEGIES

def _play_loser(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Deliberately play to help opponent win. """
    #
    # We use the hints() function to identify moves that a sane
    # opponent would play, subtract those from the available
    # cells, and move in any of the cells that remain. If
    # none, take edges for preference.
    #
    candidates = set(available_cells())
    candidates.difference_update(set(hints(player)))
    if len(candidates) > 0:
        cell = candidates.pop()
        return cell.set(player)
    return (_make_random_move(_EDGES, player) or
            _play_random(player))


def _play_random(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Play in random available cell. """
    return _make_random_move(cells, player)


def _play_easy(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Complete winning line if possible, else play at random. """
    return (_make_win_or_block(player, player) or
            _play_random(player))


def _play_hard(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Complete or block winning lines, prefer centre then corners. """
    return (_make_win_or_block(player, player) or
            _make_win_or_block(player.opponent, player) or
            _make_random_move(_CENTRE, player) or
            _make_random_move(_CORNERS, player) or
            _play_random(player))


def _play_handicap_2(player=COMPUTER):
    """ First two moves random, then expert """
    if len(moves) < 5:
        return _play_random(player)
    return _play_expert(player)


def _play_handicap_1(player=COMPUTER):
    """ First move to edge, then play as expert """
    if len(moves) < 3:
        return _make_random_move(_EDGES, player)
    return _play_expert(player)


def _play_expert(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Play expertly to not lose, the traditional 'perfect' TicTacToe """
    return (_make_win_or_block(player, player) or
            _make_win_or_block(player.opponent, player) or
            _make_forked_move(player) or
            _make_forcing_move(player) or
            _make_random_move(_CENTRE, player) or
            _make_random_move(_CORNERS, player) or
            _play_random(player))


# Possible extensions:
# - add play_cunning() to maximise winning chances against naive opponent
# - add progressive play to adjust difficulty to user's skill level

# FUNCTIONS - UTILITIES FOR COMPUTER MOVE STRATEGIES

def _make_random_move(target_cells, player=COMPUTER):
    """ Return completed cell chosen from target_cells if available. """
    cells_list = []
    for cell in target_cells:
        if cell.player == EMPTY:
            cells_list.append(cell)

    if len(cells_list) != 0:
        cell = random.choice(cells_list)
        return cell.set(player)
    return None


def _list_possible_wins_blocks(look_for_player):
    """ Return list of cells with a winning move available. """
    possible_cells = []
    for cell in available_cells():
        for line in cell.lines:
            if line._value == 2 * look_for_player._value + 0:
                possible_cells.append(cell)
    return possible_cells


def _make_win_or_block(look_for_player, fill_with_player):
    """ Return a completed cell that wins or blocks a line, or None """
    possible_cells = _list_possible_wins_blocks(look_for_player)
    if len(possible_cells) != 0:
        cell = random.choice(possible_cells)
        return cell.set(fill_with_player)
    return None


def _list_possible_forks(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Return list of available forking moves. """
    #
    # We're looking for two lines, each containing just one entry for
    # 'player', that intersect in an empty cell. That's the cell we
    # want to play in.
    #
    possible_forks = []
    for cell in available_cells():
        forks = 0
        for line in cell.lines:
            if line._value == player._value + 0 + 0:
                forks += 1
        if forks > 1:
            possible_forks.append(cell)
    return possible_forks


def _make_forked_move(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Return completed forking move, or None. """
    my_forks = _list_possible_forks(player)
    if len(my_forks) == 0:
        return None
    cell = random.choice(my_forks)
    return cell.set(player)


def _list_possible_forcing_moves(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Find a forcing move that does not make opponent fork us. """
    #
    # This one is a bit tricky. We are looking to force the opponent to
    # block us, by having two cells in a line - if he doesn't block, we
    # get to win next turn. BUT we must avoid 'forcing' him into a move
    # that wins the game for him.
    #
    # So first we find what possible forking moves he has, then we look
    # for our candidate lines and extract the two blank cells. If one
    # of those cells is *not* a possible forking move for the opponent,
    # we have to move in the *other* one.
    #
    # Got that? Good. Took me ages.
    #
    opponent_forks = _list_possible_forks(player.opponent)

    my_moves = set()
    for line in lines:
        if line._value == player._value + 0 + 0:
            temp = [cell for cell in line.cells if cell.player == EMPTY]
            for i, cell in enumerate(temp):
                if temp[i] not in opponent_forks:
                    # move in the *other* empty cell on the line
                    my_moves.add(temp[(i + 1) % 2])
    return list(my_moves)


def _make_forcing_move(player=COMPUTER):
    """ Return completed forcing move, or None. """
    cell_list = _list_possible_forcing_moves(player)
    if len(cell_list) == 0:
        return None
    cell = random.choice(cell_list)
    return cell.set(player)


#
# And, right down here, is the call to initialise the playing board.
# As an old COBOL hand I can't get used to programming upside-down.
#
if __name__ != '__main__':
    __init__()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrap your public variables and functions into another class, called `Game` or `TicTacToe`. This way you can instantiate your game by just importing the class, then doing

```
game = TicTacToe()
game.start()
```

and having that class control the game.

Right now you are basically treating your global namespace like a class, with global functions as classes, and `__init__` as the constructor, that you call excplicitly. Functions/methods with leading and trailing double underscores should normally never be called explicitly.

---

The constructor of your `Player` class takes a parameter `value`. What is that value? Better use a name that tells you *what* kind of value it is (e. g. level, age, etc.).

---

The `Player` class has this property:

```
@property
def opponent(self):
    if self == USER:
        return COMPUTER
    return USER
```

It returns the `USER` instance of `Player` in any case where it is not the `USER` itself. But what if you ask the `EMPTY` player that you are using for empty fields what its opponent is? Maybe you could instead use a variable to save the opponent and set it where you instantiate the players. It is not good practice to have the internal behaviour of classes depend on global state.

---

Having classes for `Line` and `Cell` seems a bit too much. Rather have a class `Board` which saves the positions of the players' symbols and checks when the winning-condition is fulfilled. If you want to use the `Line` and `Cell` classes to better organize your code, make them private classes of the `Board`, so that no user (even you) of your code creates instances of them where they are not needed.

---

This is hard to read and seems a bit like a math puzzle:

```
for i in range(0, 9, 3):  # rows
    lines.append(Line(i, i + 1, i + 2))
for i in range(3):  # columns
    lines.append(Line(i, i + 3, i + 6))
```

Rather write 6 lines (of code) instead of these 4 and write the values excplicitly. Using for loops here hardly gives you any value, neither concerning readability nor performance.

---

In `reset_board` you call this:

```
for cell in cells:
    cell._reset()
```

But remember that method names starting with underscores are used for private methods, and thus should not be called from outside of the class. Using a `Board` class enables you to add a single `reset()` method to it that resets all cells and lines.